# if text contains '@' change color of '@'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a solution for my problem.
I have a paragraph with some text from a twitter tweet. Now I would like to change all the '@'s to a color.

This is what I do to look for '@'s in my text:

```
if (status.indexOf("@") >= 0)
{

}
```

But now how can I change the color of the @? (Add a span and class or something ...)

The status is a variable with content for ex. like this:

```
Dita Von Teese draagt geprinte 3D-jurk  <a target="_blank" href="http://t.co/s2y6b21S0I">http://t.co/s2y6b21S0I</a> via @<a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/Knackweekend">Knackweekend</a>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without seeing your HTML, the best I can offer is a simple replace, and I'm assuming that `status` is a jQuery collection of HTML elements/nodes:

```
status.html(function(i,h){
    return h.replace(/@/g,'<span class="atSign">@</span>');
});
```

Coupled with the CSS:

```
.atSign {
    color: #f90;
}
```

Updated, since `status` appears to be a string (from the comments, below):

```
var status = '<a target="_blank" href="t.co/s2y6b21S0I">http://t.co/s2y6b21S0I</a>; via @<a target="_blank" href="twitter.com/Knackweekend">Knackweekend</a>',
    newStatus = status.replace(/@/g,'<span class="atSign">@</span>');
console.log(newStatus);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GQRRG/1/).

To colour the `@` *and* the following `a` element, with CSS:

```
.atSign,
.atSign + a {
    color: #f90;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GQRRG/3/).

To wrap the `@` *and* the following `a` element within the `span`:

```
var status = '<a target="_blank" href="t.co/s2y6b21S0I">http://t.co/s2y6b21S0I</a>; via @<a target="_blank" href="twitter.com/Knackweekend">Knackweekend</a>',
    newStatus = status.replace(/(@.+<\/a>)/g,function(a){
    return '<span class="atSign">' + a + '</span>';
    });
console.log(newStatus);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GQRRG/4/).

References:

- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: This will only replace the first occurrence of `@`

Comment: @Xotic750 You sure? It is a regex now.

Comment: @Xotic750: yeah, edited. :) I was offering a simple/quick first-answer and revising/adding references as you commented.

Comment: @David Thomas, a serialisation problem :)

Comment: The text is in variable status. In status is for ex.: Dita Von Teese draagt geprinte 3D-jurk  <a target="_blank" href="http://t.co/s2y6b21S0I">http://t.co/s2y6b21S0I</a> via @<a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/Knackweekend">Knackweekend</a>

Comment: So, that's a string? And, incidentally, to put code in comments (almost always a terrible idea) please use back-ticks `\`(your code here)\`` to surround the code. Otherwise it ends up looking like that, which isn't visually that readable.

Comment: So, how can I do this with a string? If I don't change anything I get this erorr: Object has no method 'html

Comment: Check the updates. And, in future, *please* be clear in your questions about what you're working with, whether it's an existing element, a collection of elements/nodes, a generic variable and what that variable might contain. That way we can help more accurately, and far, *far* more quickly.

Comment: The danger now with a string that contains HTML is that the `@` could also be used in an attribute and this would cause invalid HTML. Not your fault of course, but the OPs lack of information.

Comment: @niels: this was, until recently, the accepted answer, may I ask if something went wrong, or didn't work with this solution? (I don't mind losing the acceptance, I'm just curious if I can offer a better/working solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to wrap the `@` in a `span` with a `class` so that you can change the colour with CSS.

You could manipulate the DOM like this

CSS

```
.atSign {
    color: #f90;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="status">Some @ text <div>that @ contains@what</div>we will@ demonstrate</div>
```

Javascript

```
/*jslint maxerr: 50, indent: 4, browser: true */

(function () {
    "use strict";

    function walkTheDOM(node, func) {
        func(node);
        node = node.firstChild;
        while (node) {
            walkTheDOM(node, func);
            node = node.nextSibling;
        }
    }

    function getTextNodes(element) {
        var nodes = [];

        walkTheDOM(element, function (node) {
            if (node.nodeType === 3) {
                nodes.push(node);
            }
        });

        return nodes;
    }

    function highlight(element, string, classname) {
        var nodes = getTextNodes(element),
            length = nodes.length,
            stringLength = string.length,
            i = 0,
            index,
            text,
            newContent,
            span,
            node;

        while (i < length) {
            node = nodes[i];
            newContent = document.createDocumentFragment();
            text = node.nodeValue;
            index = text.indexOf(string);
            while (index !== -1) {
                newContent.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.slice(0, index)));
                text = text.slice(index + stringLength);
                span = document.createElement("span");
                span.className = classname;
                span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(string));
                newContent.appendChild(span);
                index = text.indexOf(string);
            }

            newContent.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
            node.parentNode.replaceChild(newContent, node);
            i += 1;
        }
    }

    highlight(document.getElementById("status"), "@", "atSign");
}());
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/PWcLf/)

How can you use this with your HTML string you ask?

Javascript

```
var div = document.createElement("div"),
    html;

div.innerHTML = 'Dita Von Teese draagt geprinte 3D-jurk  <a target="_blank" href="http://t.co/s2y6b21S0I">http://t.co/s2y6b21S0I</a> via @<a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/Knackweekend">Knackweekend</a>';

highlight(div, "@", "atSign");
html = div.innerHTML;

console.log(html);
```

Output

```
Dita Von Teese draagt geprinte 3D-jurk  <a target="_blank" href="http://t.co/s2y6b21S0I">http://t.co/s2y6b21S0I</a> via <span class="atSign">@</span><a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/Knackweekend">Knackweekend</a>
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/VBE3j/)

And no jquery or regexs in sight :)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a new span on same index and remove the existing item in that index.